# Huffman Coding Tree traversal

Tags: python, algorithm, compression, huffman-code

Writing Huffman Coding Algorithm in Python. Have successfully managed to create a tree based on a string input but am stuck on the best way to traverse it while generating the codes for each letter.

```
from collections import Counter
    class HuffNode:
        def __init__(self, count, letter=None):
            self.letter = letter
            self.count = count
            self.right = None
            self.left = None

    word = input()
    d = dict(Counter(word))

    Nodes = [HuffNode(d[w], w) for w in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)]

    while len(Nodes) > 1:
        a = Nodes.pop()
        b = Nodes.pop()
        c = HuffNode(a.count+b.count)
        c.left, c.right = a, b

        Nodes.append(c)
        Nodes.sort(key=lambda x: x.count, reverse=True)
```

### For a word like "hello".

`d = dict(Counter(word))` would get the frequency of each letter in the string and convert it to a dict. Thus having `{'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'h': 1, 'o': 1}` Each letter if then converted to a `HuffNode` and stored in `Nodes`

The `while` loop then proceeds to generate a tree until we only have one root

[When the loop exits I'll have:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCS9A.png) 
Whats the best way to traverse this tree then generating the codes for each letter?
Thanks

Comment: You can probably optimize your while loop with a `heapq`, to avoid sorting your entire array at each step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you would want a recursive function that, given a `HuffNode` h and a prefix p:

- if `h.letter` is not empty (i.e. h is a leaf), yields `(p, h.letter)` -> this is the code for the letter
- otherwise, calls itself on `h.left` with prefix `p + '0'` and on `h.right` with `p + '1'`

A possible implementation (not tested, may have typos):

```
def make_code(node, prefix):
    if node is None:
        return []
    if node.letter is not None:
        return [(prefix, node.letter)]
    else:
        result = []
        result.extend(make_code(h.left, prefix + '0'))
        result.extend(make_code(h.right, prefix + '1'))
        return result

codes = make_code(root, '')
```

where `root`is the Huffman tree you built in the first step. The first test (`if node is None`) is to manage lopsided nodes, where one of the children may be empty.